# Google Calendar(sharing)

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm working with a Google Apps application. Actually, I want to the access another id without using a password for that. I used OAuth and it's working well. But I am not able to share the particular person's calendar. I tried the following code.

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParam=new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParam.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxx.com");
oauthParam.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
oauthParam.setScope("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/");
URL feedUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars  full?xoauth_requestor_id=user@example.com");
CalendarService service=new CalendarService("calendar");
service.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParam,new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
AclEntry entry = new AclEntry();
entry.setScope(new AclScope(AclScope.Type.USER,"any.user"));
entry.setRole(CalendarAclRole.READ);
AclEntry insertedEntry = service.insert(feedUrl, entry);
```

For this code I got the error:

> ```
> com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
> Calendar entry does not contain title
>     at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:558)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting ACL entries instead of Calendar entries into the own calendars feed is not a good idea. Also, this API is now deprecated, use http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html for the reference.